# Getting Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException after setup MergerHandler in Sitecore 9.0u1

Tags: xconnect

I have set up merge handler for custom facet seeing [this documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-model/facets/facet-merge-handler.html).

I put sc.CustomPlugins.xml file -> App_data\config\sitecore\Collection\
And dll file -> App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine.

But when I try to load my site, I am getting **Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException** error. How to fix this issue ? 
Or why its happening?

Apart from that if I delete  sc.CustomPlugins.xml, my site is working again.

Also after set up that merge handler I am getting this issue in xconnect site.

[image]

Comment: Did you copy the new dll to xconnect\bin folder?

Comment: No I didn't copy it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dll that contains code for the new merge handler should be copied to *c:\path\toxconnect\root\bin* folder while configuration files should be copied *c:\path\toxconnect\root\App_data\config\sitecore\Collection* just as you pointed out.

Handlers are executed by xConnect for submitted operations, hence custom code needs to be reachable by xConnect service.